# Style for last td of last tr of certain class in table

Tags: css

I need to apply style to last cell of last row of class "fose_table_row".
Table is next

```
<table class="fose_table">
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fose_table_row">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fose_edit_row">
        <td colspan="4">56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fose_table_row">
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fose_edit_row">
        <td colspan="4">90</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Rows of class `fose_edit_row` are not visible rows so I need last of `fose_table_row` to be styled. 
I tried `.fose_table .fose_table_row:last-child td:last-child` and `.fose_table tr.fose_table_row:last-child td:last-child` but that doesn't seem to work. Last or of class `fose_edit_row` gets styled.  What is right way to do this? And is it even possible?

Comment: Can you also post your HTML for the problem?

Comment: edited question to better describe problem

Comment: There's an extra `</td>` under `<td>4</td>` and `iclass` under that too.

Comment: Removed the extra `</td>` while indenting the code. If it wasn't just a typo, you might want to edit it back in.

Comment: thanks, David Thomas, that was indeed typo, but only here. In code it's ok.

Comment: This question is, basically, requiring a `:last-of-class()` selector, which isn't possible in pure CSS. Solutions for this problem *will* require JavaScript, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [W3C `:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:last-child)

> The :last-child pseudo-class represents an element that is the last child of some other element.

`:last-child` will get the last element of its parent and then it will apply style if it has class `.fose_table_row`. So CSS can't solve your problem.

A possible jQuery solution:

```
$('table.fose_table').find('tr.fose_table_row').eq(-1).addClass('extra-style');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/6qxZy/)

Answer (score 1):

The only way, currently, to solve your problem (as I noted in the comments) is to use JavaScript. Using plain JavaScript, rather than a library, I'd suggest:

```
var foseTableRows = document.querySelectorAll('.fose_table_row'),
    last = foseTableRows[foseTableRows.length - 1];
console.log(last);
last.classList.add('lastFoseTableRow');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/47Ucc/).

Coupled with CSS, to apply the specific styles in order that they're reusable elsewhere without manipulating the `style` property of the specific nodes/elements.